# Blogger and unicode?

Tags: unicode, blogger

I have two questions

1. Can this code be added to blogger?
2. Can this code embed unicode fonts? and if can, please tell me the link how to do it.

Comment: What code? You haven't posted any.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your code Kotaro ,

but any code can added to blogger and and by default embedding font in web is not available . but you can use CSS 3.0 to force user to use from the font you like, this css property is 
      font-url

and you can use it as any other css property like

```
  <div style="direction:ltr;text-align:left;font-size:small;font-url:('../resources/fonts/YourFont.ttf');"> you code </div>
```

just note that this CSS property just available at css 3.0 and now just Firefox 3.5 supports it so I recommand you Ignore it for now,

if you want to show a speciall text just use from a font that you know your users have it, like (Arial , Tahoma , Verdana ) for windows usres

for code you can use these software

1- copysourceashtml
http://copysourceashtml.codeplex.com/

that is a opensource software

[copysourceashtml http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=copysourceashtml&DownloadId=78099](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=copysourceashtml&DownloadId=78099)

2- Postable
http://vahid.nasiri.googlepages.com/postable.rar

[image: Postable software]